# Boxing the contents of all theorems but not the theorem heading

Tags: amsthm, framed, examples, box

I created a theorem environment for examples and I want to have them boxed underneath the heading.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}                                                                 
{5mm}                                                                                   
{5mm}                                                                                   
{}                                                                                      
{}                                                                                      
{\bfseries}                                                                         
{}                                                                                      
{\newline}                                                                              
{}                                                      
\theoremstyle{break}                                                                    
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{exmp}
This text should be framed in a box, but not the heading "Example".
\end{exmp}

\end{document}
```

Can I add an `\fbox{}` into this newtheorenstyle so I can use `\begin{exmp} Text text text \end{exmp}` and the "Text text text" will be inside of a frame box?

Comment: See my answer to your other question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543643/29873

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage you to have a look at [thmbox](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/thmbox/thmbox.pdf) which was created precisely for that kind of purpose.

The following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage%[nounderline]
{thmbox}
\newtheorem[L]{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem[L]{ex}[thm]{Example}


\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
\end{ex}

\vspace{45em}

\begin{ex}
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
Some text, some more text, a sufficient amount to get a full box with several lines.
\end{ex}



\end{document}



\end{document}
```

produces almost what you want:

[image]

and breaks nicely:

[image]

Refer to the manual for more tweaking option, but I believe that this will be more elegant than your "hand-made" solution.

Answer (score 1):

This accomplished it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}                                                                 
{5mm}                                                                                   
{5mm}                                                                                   
{}                                                                                      
{}                                                                                      
{\bfseries}                                                                         
{}                                                                                      
{\newline}                                                                              
{}                                                      
\theoremstyle{break}                                                                    
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
\begin{exmp}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{#1}%
\end{exmp}}

\begin{document}

\example{Text text text}

\end{document}
```

The frame is the width of the main body and the example inside is left-justified.

Comment: My understanding is that oframed in the framed package allows these frames to naturally break across pages, but I could not get that to work.  Would this be a new question?